# Evaluating the PDF of the difference of independent gamma random variables at zero

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution, gamma-function, gamma-distribution

**Question: What is the density at zero for the pdf of the difference of independent gamma random variables when the sum of the shape parameters is less than or equal to one?**

---

**Motivation for asking:**

Given two independent gamma random variables $X\sim\mathcal{G}(\alpha_{X},\beta_{X})$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{G}(\alpha_{Y},\beta_{Y})$, the PDFs (using the shape-rate parameterization) of $X$ and $Y$ are
\begin{align}
\tag{1}
f_{X}(x) &=\frac{\beta_{X}^{\alpha_{X}}}{\Gamma(\alpha_{X})}x^{\alpha_{X}-1}e^{-\beta_{X}x},\\
\tag{2}
f_{Y}(y) &=\frac{\beta_{Y}^{\alpha_{Y}}}{\Gamma(\alpha_{Y})}y^{\alpha_{Y}-1}e^{-\beta_{Y}y},
\end{align}
where the parameters $\alpha_{X}$, $\alpha_{Y}$, $\beta_{X}$, and $\beta_{Y}$ are all greater than zero.  Now define the random variable $Z=X-Y$. The pdf of $Z$, $f_{Z}$, can be found by the cross-correlation of $f_{X}$ and $f_{Y}$ to give
\begin{equation}
f_{Z}(z)=\frac{\beta_{X}^{\alpha_{X}}\beta_{Y}^{\alpha_{Y}}}{\Gamma(\alpha_{X})\Gamma(\alpha_{Y})}
\begin{cases}
e^{\beta_{Y}z}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha_{X}-1}(x-z)^{\alpha_{Y}-1}e^{-(\beta_{X}+\beta_{Y})x}\,\mathrm{d}x & z<0\\
e^{-\beta_{X}z}\int_{0}^{\infty}y^{\alpha_{Y}-1}(x+z)^{\alpha_{X}-1}e^{-(\beta_{X}+\beta_{Y})y}\,\mathrm{d}y & z>0.
\end{cases}\tag{3}
\end{equation}

Now to find $f_{Z}(0)$ one simply substitutes $z=0$ into the above expressions for $f_{Z}$ when $z<0$ and $z>0$.  After the substitution, it can be seen that both pieces will give the same answer of
\begin{align}
\tag{4.a}
f_{Z}(0)
&=\frac{\beta_{X}^{\alpha_{X}}\beta_{Y}^{\alpha_{Y}}}{\Gamma(\alpha_{X})\Gamma(\alpha_{Y})}
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha_{X}+\alpha_{Y}-2}e^{-(\beta_{X}+\beta_{Y})x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
\tag{4.b}
&=\frac{\beta_{X}^{\alpha_{X}}\beta_{Y}^{\alpha_{Y}}}{\Gamma(\alpha_{X})\Gamma(\alpha_{Y})(\beta_{X}+\beta_{Y})^{\alpha_{X}+\alpha_{Y}-1}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\alpha_{X}+\alpha_{Y}-2}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
\tag{4.c}
&=\frac{\beta_{X}^{\alpha_{X}}\beta_{Y}^{\alpha_{Y}}}{\Gamma(\alpha_{X})\Gamma(\alpha_{Y})(\beta_{X}+\beta_{Y})^{\alpha_{X}+\alpha_{Y}-1}}\Gamma(\alpha_{X}+\alpha_{Y}-1)
\end{align}

**Here is where my question comes into play...** The quantity $\Gamma(\alpha_{X}+\alpha_{Y}-1)$ is not defined for $\alpha_{X}+\alpha_{Y}=1$, and even more disturbing is negative for $0<\alpha_{X}+\alpha_{Y}<1$. **How can this be when the quantity $\alpha_{X}+\alpha_{Y}$ can take on these values? How would one find the value of $f_{Z}(0)$?**

Comment: If $B\subseteq\mathbb R$ is measurable with $\lambda(B)=0$ where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure and $f$ serves as PDF of some random variable $Z$ then **any** nonnegative Borelmeasurable function $g$ that satisfies $\{z\in\mathbb R\mid f(z)\neq g(z)\}\subseteq B$ serves as PDF of $Z$. So actually in general you cannot even speak of **the** value of the PDF taken at $0$. If you find an expression for $f_Z$ that  give troubles for $z=0$ then you can just choose some value $f_Z(0)\geq0$, since $\lambda(\{0\})=0$.

Comment: Actually I did not really dive into question and am not able to give you a complete answer. Only one thing triggered me: the questioning "What is the density for the PDF at zero..?" This because you can just take *any* non-negative value for it. If there is a PDF $f$ then for any $c>0$ the function $f_c$ prescribed by $x\mapsto f(x)$ if $x\neq0$ and $x\mapsto c$ otherwise is also a PDF of that same distribution. This because $\int_Bf(x)dx=\int_Bf_cdx$ for every measurable $B$. My comment only deals with that issue. My name is not Moses, but that doesn't exclude that your are a brother :-)

Comment: Is there not a typo in equation (3) (and subsequent equations)? Am I mistaken, or should we have $e^{-(\beta_X+\beta_Y)y}$, not $e^{-(\alpha_X+\alpha_Y)y}$?

Comment: @ThomasWinckelman Yes you're right. Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the issue resides at Eq. (4.c). The integral definition for $\Gamma(z)$ is only defined for $\Re z>0$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(z):=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\qquad\text{for}\ \Re z>0.
\end{equation}

For $z\leq0$, $\Gamma(z)$ is defined by analytic continuation.  Therefore, if $0<\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}\leq1$, the integral in Eq. (4.b) is:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\alpha_{3}-2}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=-\left(\lim_{t\to\infty}\Gamma(\alpha_{3}-1,t)-\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\Gamma(\alpha_{3}-1,t)\right)\\
&=
\begin{cases}
\infty &\text{for}\ 0<\alpha_{3}\leq1\,,\\
\Gamma(\alpha_{3}-1)
&\text{for}\ \alpha_{3}>1\,.
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\alpha_{3}=\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}$. Using this solution, $f_{Z}(0)$ is

\begin{equation}
f_{Z}(0) =
\begin{cases}
\infty &\text{for}\ 0<\alpha_{3}\leq1\,,\\
\frac{\beta_{1}^{\alpha_{1}}\beta_{2}^{\alpha_{2}}\Gamma(\alpha_{3}-1)}{\beta_{3}^{\alpha_{3}-1}\Gamma(\alpha_{1})\Gamma(\alpha_{2})}
&\text{for}\ \alpha_{3}>1\,.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}